# Appsync response mapping template json key name change

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

What would be the right way to change json response key value in aws appsync response mapping template?

JSON that I get looks like this:

```
{
  "tenant_id": 1,
  "id": "bd8ce6a8-8532-47ec-8b7f-dcd1f1603320",
  "header": "Header name",
  "visible": true
}
```

and what I would like to pass forward is

```
{
  "tenantId": 1,
  "id": "bd8ce6a8-8532-47ec-8b7f-dcd1f1603320",
  "header": "Header name",
  "visible": true
}
```

Schema wants tenant id in form of tenantID and lambda returns it in form of tenant_id. I could change it in lambda but I would like to know how to do it in response mapping template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this via the response mapping template for the field you are resolving to in the following manner:

Consider the JSON response from your lambda to be stored in the `response` variable, then you can return something like this.

```
$#set($result = {
 "tenantId": ${response.tenant_id},
 "id": "${response.id}",
 "header": "${response.header}",
 "visible": $response.visible
})

$util.toJson($result)
```

Alternatively, you could also mutate your response from the lambda by setting a `tenantId` field, something like `#set( $response.tenantId = $response.tenant_id )`. Let me know if you still face an issue.

Thanks,
Shankar

Comment: I ended up using Lodash mapKeys and cameCase methods in the lambda handler so I could do it in one place for all GraphQL queries. But it is useful to know the response mapping way too for special cases. Thank you!

Comment: I wanted to do something similar with a response coming from DynamoDB instead of lambda. For an unknown reason, your second solution `#set( $ctx.result.newkey = $ctx.result.oldkey)` (which I prefer as it keeps the rest of the data intact) doesn't work (my new key is always null). So I implemented the first one and it works like a charm. Thanks :)